# Building adjacency matrix from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a plain JavaScript array of objects, say e.g.

```
const drawings = [
  {
    name: "Foo",
    category: "widget"
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    category: "widget"
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    category: "fidget"
  },
]
```

etc, where both the name and category have duplicates. What I want to end up with is essentially a list of objects (this is to meet the interface for a 3rd party library), where each object represents a name, and then for each category there is a property that is either true or false, depending on the original list. So for the example the output would be:

```
const output = [
  {
    name: "Foo",
    widget: true,
    fidget: false
  },
  {
  {
    name: "Bar",
    widget: true,
    fidget: true
  },
]
```

Comment: Will you know all the categories before hand or will you need to infer them from the `drawings` object?

Comment: Need to infer them. Could do it in a separate step, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first go through and make an object of your categories with the categories as keys and default values as `false`.

Then you can assign this to each object and set the correct keys to true as you go through.

```js
const drawings = [{name: "Foo",category: "widget"},{name: "Bar",category: "widget"},{name: "Bar",category: "fidget"},]

// make category object where everything is false
let category_obj = drawings.reduce((a, item) => (a[item.category] = false, a), {})

let output = drawings.reduce((a, {name, category}) => {
    // assign cat
    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(name)) a[name] = Object.assign({}, {name}, category_obj)
    // set to true if the correct category
    a[name][category] = true
   return a
}, {})

// the above makes an object, but you only want the array of values
console.log(Object.values(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the categories or if you have infered them as you suggested, you could use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like such:

```
drawings.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    if (!acc.some(elt => elt.name === curr.name)) {
      acc.push({name: curr.name, widget: false, fidget: false})
    }
    const i = acc.findIndex(elt => elt.name === curr.name)
    acc[i][curr.category] = true
    return acc
}, [])
```

Comment: The line where you call `acc.push`, is there a way to do it without having to list out all of the categories? That's what I'm trying to avoid hard coding -- i.e. I can easily have an array of the categories, but can't have them hard coded like that. That's why I'm stuck.